# error: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open one file this way, but getting that exception on the marked line:

```
std::string str = "c:/qsdqsdsq/qsdqsdsq/qsdqsd.txt+++++qsdqsdqsd";
FILE *abc = fopen(str.substr(0, str.find_first_of("+++++")).c_str(), "w+b"); // marked line
```

Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Project.exe
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

The debugger points on the 2296th line (which only contains `}` after the `_Xout_of_range("invalid string position");` line) of the `xstring` file.

How may I fix this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not a C++ exception, that looks like a .NET exception. Are you really coding C++, or managed C++-CLI?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm using .NET only to make ODBC connections with my DB.

Comment: You're mixing C++ (`std::string`) and C (`fopen`) APIs.. Why not use `std::ofstream` and friends?

Comment: @lethal-guitar, so what? It's pretty legal.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy sure it is, but it's suboptimal style IMHO - and you don't get the benefits of RAII (automatically closing file descriptors) as provided by the C++ APIs

Comment: Oh, and you *did* try an search for the exception? Then you would have found e.g. [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception.aspx) which might give you some insights on how to get more information.

Comment: This exception is thrown if either start is not in the range [0, str.length) or start + length is not within [0, str.length]. As start is 0 and find_first_of returns either a valid index or std::string::npos if none of the characters is found in this case it means that std::string::npos was returned. As this is not possible with the code you have posted I assume that what you have posted is not the real code causing the exception.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your string operation as you posted it: [see here](https://eval.in/130128). Please post your real code.

Comment: @Muepe, you're right. Would you please post your comment as an answer to set it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is thrown if either `start` is not in the range `[0, str.length)` or `start + length` is not within `[0, str.length]`. As `start` is 0 and `find_first_of` returns either a valid index or `std::string::npos` if none of the characters is found in this case it means that `std::string::npos` was returned by `find_first_of`. As this is not possible with the code you have posted I assume that what you have posted is not the actual code causing the exception.